# Google datastore multiple values for the same property

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am using Google Datastore for an Android application, the backend is written in Java. In one table, I want to set multiple values to the same property:

```
Entity newGroup = new Entity("group");
newGroup.setProperty("member", "A");
newGroup.setProperty("member", "B");
newGroup.setProperty("member", "C");
datastore.put(newGroup);
```

I then want to query to find all groups a user belongs to, I do the following:

```
    Query.Filter filter = new Query.FilterPredicate("member", Query.FilterOperator.EQUAL, "A");
    Query q = new Query("group").setFilter(filter);

    PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);
```

However, the query does not generate any result. In the documentation it is mentioned that if at least one value of the property matches the filter, the entity is returned, which confuses me.

Thank you!

Comment: How long between your put and your query?

Comment: The actions are triggered by user interaction, so I think this should not be a problem.

Comment: Well eventual consistency is an important concept of datastore, so yes it's possible that it is relevant.

Comment: In your example, `member` will equal `C` because you're overwriting `A` and `B`. You need a `List<String>` as per Andrei's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
List<String> members = new ArrayList<String>(3);
members.add("A");
members.add("B");
members.add("C");

Entity newGroup = new Entity("group");
newGroup.setProperty("member", members);
datastore.put(newGroup);
```

Comment: It did not work for me. The entry in datastore looks like:
id=5073368378245120 [{"stringValue":"A,B,C"}]
However, the query still does not find it.

Comment: I don't recognize this representation. It should look like this in the Datastore viewer: `["A","B","C"]`

Comment: Oh, you are right. The problem was in completely other place... Sorry about that. The problem is that I have a Cloud Endpoints method
@ApiMethod(name = "addGroup")
 public void addGroup(@Named("session") String sessionString,
                                    @Named("members") List<String> members) throws ForbiddenException
{
    
}
When I call the method from the code, the second parameter (the list) has only one entry which is in form "A, B, C" if the method was called from the client with an ArrayList of 3 entries.
Any ideas about this? Thank you for the help anyway!