# Storing and Searching an Array of Strings in Google App Engine DataStore (Java)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to implement a **many to one** relationship. I plan to store an array of keys (datastore entity key) of one model in the other model's entity as `List<String>`.

e.g. Say 4 entities of Model A (a1,a2,a3,a4) have datastore keys : key1, key2, key3 and key4 respectively. Now I store an entity of Model B which has a property called "ids" as `List<String>`. "ids" has these `String` as the elements: key1, key2, key3 and key4.

Its all fine till now.
But how do I query the model B for each of these ids now?

What I want to do is something like this:

`query.setFilter(FilterOperator.EQUAL.of(ids,"key1"))`.

Clearly this can not be done right now.
Now what I am doing is fetching the ids property of each B entity and then manually deserializing into a list of string and then checking if the key is present or not.

As you can see this is  highly inefficient. How should I approach here? Should I store these mapping in a separate Model. I don't want to handle Joins, but I will have to if I can't get anything else than the present solution.

I am not using JPA or JDO and I plan not to use them.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please see:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30733825/google-datastore-multiple-values-for-the-same-property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query with EQUAL filter works fine for lists of values. Make sure you pass correct value when executing this query.

For example, you can store List, if you only use this entity on the server side.

If you need this list on the client side, and you always store keys for entities of the same kind, you can store a list of `ids` (List) or 'names` (List) used to create these keys. This will take much less space.

Comment: thanks for the answer. can you tell me about the efficiency of searching such a multi value property for one value. how does gae handle it?

Comment: It is as fast as querying for a single value. The only issue to keep in mind is that every value in this list will result in one extra entry for each composite index involving this property. If you use many composite indexes including this property, it may get expensive.